# Using thermald for cpu to stop overheating

Tags: cpu, temperature

Sometimes, my laptop with `Intel Core i3` is overheating. For example today.

```
$ sensors
radeon-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +59.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +58.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +55.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          15.30 V
```

How to use `thermald` to fix it? The file `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` is missing.
Should I create one? How would it look like?

Comment: How "overheating" in that example ? The actual temperatures are all less than 60 deg, the limits are all 100 deg or above. Worry when anything goes over 85 degrees.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant My fan starts whiring when temperatures are about 50 deg. It's unpleasant whiring. Now, temperatures are under 40 deg and I have opened the same applications. I have no idea why sometimes temperatures go over 50 deg and the fan whirs. (It's about once in a week)

Comment: I can see your related question in 2017. The fan is just doing its job -- keeping the hardware safe. If it is noisy doing that, suspect dust in a filter, on the blades, inside the heat exchanger, or maybe the thermal compound had dried. My Laptop gets throttled at 70 C (when streaming), and I need to do all those things every two years, which gets it back down to around 60 C max, and makes it silent again too. I would never consider raising the 70 C limit -- Samsung knows best.

Comment: "It's about once in a week" probably an automated task, a cron job or systemd timer?

Comment: @td211 No it's not regular. I expect that in spring or summer it will be more often.

Comment: I can't imagine a proper solution without making your device slow. If performance is not a concern try setting scaling governor to powersave which will make the CPU much more conservative in its energy usage. I recommend that you get a better cooling system (maybe a passive or quiet one) instead of messing with the CPU speed.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant in 2017 it was another laptop. Now, I have a new one (it's an older one, my friend gave to me, because he had troubles with Windows there, so I can utilize it with Linux yet, for my needs it is sufficient)

Comment: You could write a bash script for that.

Comment: Most processors should have an adjustable threshold that limits the maximum temperature, for example AMD CPUs have tctl-temp which can be controlled with ryzenadj, and you may be able to find something similar for Intel.

Answer (score 1):

> How to use thermald to fix it?

After installing `thermald` ensure that Intel p-state is loaded correctly by:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
intel_pstate # The desired output.
```

Old CPUs may use the `intel_cpufreq` or `acpi_cpufreq` driver

It is possible to force the autosave mode instead of the performance one by installing `cpufrequtils` then changing the `GOVERNOR` parameter to `powersave`.

```
sudo sed -i 's/^GOVERNOR=.*/GOVERNOR="powersave"/' /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils
```

> The file /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml is missing

Yes, because `thermald` use the default Zero configuration mode, the XML config file will be ignored.

> Should I create one? How would it look like?

You can generate the XML file by executing `sudo dptfxtract`, after installing `dptfxtract` (In some Linux distributions it should be installed as dependency for thermald). It will generate a `/var/run/thermald/thermal-conf.xml.auto` file. See `man thermald` and `man thermal-conf.xml`.

Comment: Here is the output of $ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
intel_cpufreq
intel_cpufreq
intel_cpufreq
intel_cpufreq

Comment: $ cat /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils | grep powersave
GOVERNOR="powersave"

Comment: $ sudo dptfxtract
DPTF Tables Extraction Utility 
Copyright (c) 2000 - 2019 Intel Corporation
No valid tables found

Comment: So, dptfxtract didn't generate `/var/run/thermald/thermal-conf.xml.auto`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're dealing with some overheating issues on your laptop, which can be pretty common, especially with intensive use or as the device ages. `thermald` is a great tool for managing and preventing overheating on Linux systems with Intel CPUs, as it uses various sensors to monitor temperatures and applies cooling strategies accordingly.

If `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` is missing, `thermald` can still run with its default configurations. However, creating a custom configuration file can help you tailor cooling strategies more effectively for your specific needs.

You can try the below steps:
First, ensure that `thermald` is Installed:
If `thermald` isn't installed on your system, you can install it using your distribution's package manager. For example, on Ubuntu or Debian-based systems:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

Next step is starting `thermald`:
Once installed, `thermald` should start automatically with its default configuration. You can ensure it's running with:

```
sudo systemctl start thermal
```

If you wish to have `thermald` start at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable thermald
```

Next step is reating a Custom Configuration File:
If you want to create a custom configuration, start by creating the `thermal-conf.xml` file in the `/etc/thermald/` directory. You can start with a basic template and adjust it according to your needs.

Here's a very basic example of what the `thermal-conf.xml` file could look like. This example doesn't apply specific cooling measures but gives you a structure to start with:

```
<ThermalConfiguration>
    <Platform>
        <Name>Example Platform</Name>
        <ProductID>0x0000</ProductID>
        <Preference>QUIET</Preference>
        <ThermalZones>
            <ThermalZone>
                <Type>cpu</Type>
                <TripPoints>
                    <TripPoint>
                        <Temperature>80000</Temperature>
                        <type>passive</type>
                        <ControlType>SEQUENTIAL</ControlType>
                    </TripPoint>
                </TripPoints>
            </ThermalZone>
        </ThermalZones>
        <CoolingDevices>
            <CoolingDevice>
                <Type>Processor</Type>
                <Instance>0</Instance>
                <SamplingPeriod>2</SamplingPeriod>
                <ControlType>SEQUENTIAL</ControlType>
            </CoolingDevice>
        </CoolingDevices>
    </Platform>
</ThermalConfiguration>
```

You can adjust Your Configurations as follows:
**Temperature**: The temperature values in the `<TripPoint>` sections are in millidegrees Celsius. Adjust these according to the temperatures you wish to target for cooling actions.

**Type and ControlType:** These can be modified based on the specific cooling mechanisms your system supports. `SEQUENTIAL` is a common control type, but your system may support others.

**ProductID**: This is optional and can be used to apply configurations to specific hardware models.

After you've created or modified `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml`, restart thermald to apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart thermal
```

You should keep in mind that the effectiveness of thermald and any custom configurations will depend on your specific hardware capabilities and the cooling strategies supported by your system's BIOS and other hardware-level controls. It's a good idea to start with minimal changes, monitor the system's behavior, and adjust your configurations as needed.

Comment: Thank you. My laptop is `Lenovo G50`. How would `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` look like in my case? If you need, I can send more information about my hardware.

Comment: Please send more info

Comment: `description: Notebook
    product: 20351 (LENOVO_MT_20351_BU_idea_FM_Leno)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo G50-70`

Comment: You can start with a basic thermal-conf.xml template and tweak it as needed. See:

<ThermalConfiguration>
    <Platform>
        <Name>Lenovo G50</Name>
        <ThermalZones>
            <ThermalZone>
                <Type>cpu</Type>
                <TripPoints>
                    <TripPoint>
                        <Temperature>80000</Temperature>
                        <Type>passive</Type>
                    </TripPoint>
                </TripPoints>
            </ThermalZone>
        </ThermalZones>
    </Platform>
</ThermalConfiguration>

Comment: I'm new to it. I don't know how to `tweak it as needed`.